# How does Freddy work?

Tags: dead-by-daylight

I started playing Dead by Daylight for the first time in a while but when I went to play Freddy I noticed that a lot had changed. I couldn't find any patch notes explaining the update so does anyone know what has changed with Freddy and how to use his abilities?

Comment: What changes did you notice exactly?

Comment: His rework, with the dream snares and all of that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DbD's recent patch notes should have popped up when you logged in following an update.

But, if you really want me to repeat the [3.1.0 patch notes](https://forum.deadbydaylight.com/en/discussion/77032/patch-note-3-1-0-mid-chapter/p1?new=1) here:

Freddy's new ability set includes:

### Gameplay and Power changes

- Microsleep

  - Awake Survivors will see The Nightmare within 16 meters, The Nightmare will be intermittent from 16 meters to 32 meters, and while awake Survivors will hear The Nightmare emit a Terror Radius of 32 meters.
- Falling Asleep

  - Survivors fall asleep passively over 60 seconds. Once asleep survivors see The Nightmare and hear The Nightmare emit a 2D 32 meter Lullaby instead of a Terror Radius. Once asleep Survivors will see the aura of an Alarm Clock on a dresser.
- Waking Up

  - An awake Survivor can wake up a sleeping Survivor.
  - Survivors can wake up by failing skill checks.

    - ...unless the Red Paint Brush addon is used
  - Survivors can wake up by going to and removing an Alarm Clock off a dresser.
  - It takes progressively longer for an alarm clock or another survivor to wake up a survivor each time they are woken up this way.  This was omitted from the official patch notes.

### Dream abilities

- Dream Snares

  - Dream Snares slow and reveal a Survivors location.
  - Only effective and visible towards Sleeping Survivors.
  - Killers start with 8 tokens, each Snare costs 1 token to place. Only 8 traps can be placed at one time.
  - Equipping the Garden Rake, Prototype Claws, or Paint Thinner addons replaces your 8 Dream Snares with 10 Dream Pallets.
- Dream Projection

  - Channel the ability to create a husk of The Nightmare at the targeted generator, complete the channel to take the position of the husk.

    - If the Class Photo addon is equipped, **all** generators start spewing blood instead of a husk appearing
  - Can be cancelled.

    - ...unless you used the Class Photo addon
  - For each sleeping Survivor gain a 15% cool down reduction on Dream Projection.